How to avoid code duplication in Windows Forms C#?
I don't know how to avoid code duplication in my program in Windows Forms.
I added an OK button that saved a text file to TextBox.
 private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         string fileName = NameOfForm.Text;
         string path = $@"C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Эстелларио/Forms/{fileName}.txt";

         using (var stream = File.Create(path))
         {
         };

         TextOFForm.Visible = true;
         SaveTextButton.Visible = true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Oh No!!!");
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
 }

Afterwards I tried to do the same with the Enter key, but I didn't understand how to do it without duplicating the code:
private void NameOfForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
         {
             string fileName = NameOfForm.Text;
             string path = $@"C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Эстелларио/Forms/{fileName}.txt";

             using (var stream = File.Create(path))
             {
             };

             TextOFForm.Visible = true;
             SaveTextButton.Visible = true;
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Oh No!!!");
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
 }


Move the KeyCode if-condition off the try, so that it'll wrap it. Then, make a separate method containing only the try-catch. Call that method from both the event handlers.

In addition to @MarioVernari's suggestion, you're going to find your users get very, very annoyed if something goes wrong and they get two separate MessageBox's that display. At the very least, combine them into one with MessageBox.Show("Oh No!! " + ex.Message).

It might be something like this:
private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => GetFile();

private void NameOfForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
        GetFile();
}

private void GetFile() 
{
    try  
    {
         using var stream = File
             .Create($@"C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Эстелларио/Forms/{NameOfForm.Text}.txt");
         // ...
         TextOFForm.Visible = SaveTextButton.Visible = true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex) 
     { 
        MessageBox.Show($"Oh No!!! {ex.Message}"); 
     }
}


Answer is right but code style is very confusing for an obvious beginner... A little bracket never hurt nobody...

@DenisSchaf It's not a point of concern.

I would recommend placing the code to create the file in a separate class and provide a better name. Using a separate class means that if you want to use the code it is not attached to a form so other forms or classes can use the code.
(bool success, Exception exception) is known as deconstruction which shown below provides access to if the method was successful and if not provide the exception.
internal class FileOperations
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a file with the specified name under a specific directory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">The name of the file.</param>
    /// <returns>A tuple indicating the success status and any exception that occurred.</returns>
    public static (bool success, Exception exception) CreateNewFile(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            using var stream = File.Create(Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Эстелларио\\Forms", $"{fileName}.txt"));
            return (true, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return (false, e);
        }
    }
}

Calling the above method.

You can adjust the error message.
Add the remainder of your code
Repeat for other buttons and KeyDown event.

private void createNewFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NameOfForm.Text))
    {
        var (success, exception) = FileOperations.CreateNewFile(NameOfForm.Text);
        if (success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File created successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Missing file name");
    }
}


I guess creation of a file it's not a goal for OP. A place for the useful actions is missing.
